# Will my dicts of dicts work for this Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm starting off by trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm here: http://thomas.pelletier.im/2010/02/dijkstras-algorithm-python-implementation/. The issue is is my matrix looks like this:

```
    {
      2845: {27026: {'weight': 0.05950338}, 83860: {'weight': 0.013386887}},
     12422: {27023: {'weight': 0.0787193}, 27026: {'weight': 0.041424256}, 59721: {'weight': 0.11553069}},
     27022: {27025: {'weight': 0.1283993}, 83860: {'weight': 0.11746721}},
     27023: {12422: {'weight': 0.0787193}, 27025: {'weight': 0.22683257}},
     27025: {27022: {'weight': 0.1283993}, 27023: {'weight': 0.22683257}, 27026: {'weight': 0.20290035}},
     27026: {2845: {'weight': 0.05950338}, 12422: {'weight': 0.041424256}, 27025: {'weight': 0.20290035}},
     59721: {12422: {'weight': 0.11553069}},
     83860: {2845: {'weight': 0.013386887}, 27022: {'weight': 0.11746721}}
}
```

Will this still work with the above algorithm or will I have to make a slight ajustment and if so, what?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here the algorithm I've implemented:

```
def dijkstra(self, graph, start, end):
        D = {} # Final distances dict
        P = {} # Predecessor dict

        for node in graph.keys():
            D[node] = -1 # Vertices are unreachable
            P[node] = ""
        D[start] = 0 # The start vertex needs no move
        unseen_nodes = graph.keys() # All nodes are unseen

        while len(unseen_nodes) > 0:
            shortest = None
            node = ''
            for temp_node in unseen_nodes:
                if shortest == None:
                    shortest = D[temp_node]
                    node = temp_node
                elif (D[temp_node] < shortest):
                    shortest = D[temp_node]
                    node = temp_node
            unseen_nodes.remove(node)
            for child_node, child_value in graph[node].items():
                if D[child_node] < D[node] + child_value:
                    D[child_node] = D[node] + child_value
                    P[child_node] = node
        path = []
        node = end
        while not (node == start):
            if path.count(node) == 0:
                path.insert(0, node) # Insert the predecessor of the current node
                node = P[node] # The current node becomes its predecessor
            else:
                break
        path.insert(0, start) # Finally, insert the start vertex
        return path
```

The matrix I'm using is as above, the matrix the algorithm wants is:

```
... graph = {
...     'A': {'B': 10, 'D': 4, 'F': 10},
...     'B': {'E': 5, 'J': 10, 'I': 17},
...     'C': {'A': 4, 'D': 10, 'E': 16},
...     'D': {'F': 12, 'G': 21},
...     'E': {'G': 4},
...     'F': {'H': 3},
...     'G': {'J': 3},
...     'H': {'G': 3, 'J': 5},
...     'I': {},
...     'J': {'I': 8},
... }
```

Comment: what you linked is a python implementation, why don't you just try it?

Comment: did you put dijstra code inside a class? (in this case your first argument is `self`, thus you'll have four arguments)

Comment: I get the error:
if D[child_node] < D[node] + child_value:
exceptions.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'

Comment: it seems you're changing the Dijkstra's algorithm you linked at. Please provide your code to let us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the given source code example the weight was just an integer, not a dict. Since your graph has a dict with a "weight" key, you have to change the code according to that.

here is the correct version of your code:

```
def dijkstra(self, graph, start, end):
        D = {} # Final distances dict
        P = {} # Predecessor dict

        for node in graph.keys():
            D[node] = -1 # Vertices are unreachable
            P[node] = ""
        D[start] = 0 # The start vertex needs no move
        unseen_nodes = graph.keys() # All nodes are unseen

        while len(unseen_nodes) > 0:
            shortest = None
            node = ''
            for temp_node in unseen_nodes:
                if shortest == None:
                    shortest = D[temp_node]
                    node = temp_node
                elif (D[temp_node] < shortest):
                    shortest = D[temp_node]
                    node = temp_node
            unseen_nodes.remove(node)
            for child_node, child_value in graph[node].items():
                if D[child_node] < D[node] + child_value['weight']:  # I changed the code here
                    D[child_node] = D[node] + child_value['weight']   # I changed the code here
                    P[child_node] = node
        path = []
        node = end
        while not (node == start):
            if path.count(node) == 0:
                path.insert(0, node) # Insert the predecessor of the current node
                node = P[node] # The current node becomes its predecessor
            else:
                break
        path.insert(0, start) # Finally, insert the start vertex
        return path
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but it depends on your code. If you would like a more complete answer please post the rest of the code.

Also it will probably be more of a headache to work with dicts than just making an 2D array. If you really want to use dicts I would recommend using a [default dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: I'm literally just trying to get the algorithm from the link to work with the matrix above.